# Is my NGINX conf file correct

Tags: nginx, centos

I am new to NGINX and I can't tell if I set my conf file up properly. I am trying to serve an index.html file located in the data/www directory. I did a lot of research and I can't seem to figure it out. I have nginx installed on a ec2 running centOS 6.5. Any pointers on how to get this up and running would be greatly appreciated. I have been trying to wrap my head around this for a while now. Thank you in advance!

```
    user  nginx;
    worker_processes  1;

    error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
    pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;


    events {
        worker_connections  1024;
    }


    http {
        include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
        default_type  application/octet-stream;

        log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                          '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                          '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

        access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

        sendfile        on;
        #tcp_nopush     on;

        keepalive_timeout  65;

        #gzip  on;

        server {
           listen 80;
           server_name <my elastic ip address>;

           location / {
             root /data/www/;
             index index.html;
           }
         }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes,
Your Configuration file is correct.

NOTE:

- working:First check your nginx server is running or not, by typing your ip:port(that you given in conf file) in browser.If running it will display nginx current version details.
- ACCESS: you can access your file by using command like this.

> http://your_ip_addr:port/application name/file_name

*application name:the name given for that app,
for example

```
location /html {
    ......
   }
```

then you application name will become html.